# If div becomes larger then a specific height, make it static?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a height that is controlled by jQuery. I have a script that expands the height ("Show More"). Problem is, that the div is set to `position: fixed;`, so when you expand it enough that content is outside the window, you cant see it.

What i would like is a jQuery script that makes the div static and not fixed when it expands outside the window.

```
#left {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 167px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    }
```

I have no idea how to write this.

Thanks in advance! Have a nice day.

Edit: Almost forgot, i'll post the expand jQuery function if needed, but i didn't think so.

Comment: Why don´t you change the css when expanding it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#left').css('position', 'static');
```

or better:

```
$('#left').toggleClass('expanded');
```

with CSS:

```css
#left.expanded {position: static;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WPUzm/